# VScode automatic compile include inside .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to use VScode with C#, but it seems that I have to include every .cs script inside the .csproj file to resolve namespaces. I'm new to C# programming so I'm probably doing it wrong, I'm used to NodeJS import/export and require, it's disturbing to have to declare every script in a single file.

.csproj :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Main_Server.cs"/>
        <Compile Include="Testing/test.cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

test.cs :

```cs
namespace MyNamespace.Test {
   public class Testing {}
}
```

Main_Server.cs :

```cs
//Here I can import my namespace with using MyNamespace.Test
//But only if I entered it before in the .csproj file
namespace MyNamespace {
   public class Main(){
   }
}
```

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced with this alone but what I can say is that the .cs files don't need to be listed in .csproj. What do you see when you type "dotnet build" in the console? Did you paste the full code or did you omit something that might be important?

Comment: Ho, so my build work fine, I got distracted by another problem, that why I thought my build didn't work. But my Vscode Intellisense still suffer from that issue. Is this related to Omnisharp or the C# vscode extension ?

Answer (score 0):

I found why VScode IntelliSense won't work correctly with C# namespaces.

Omnisharp apprently don't know how to resolve namespaces dynamically like the compiler do. You have to tell him where to find your .cs scripts.

In your .csproj file, just add a glob search to get every .cs files inside a specific directory

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Main_Server.cs"/>  <!--- Including my main script -->
        <Compile Include="Testing/**/*.cs"/> <!-- Including every .cs files in every subfolder inside the "Testing" folder -->
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Be careful to not include the same script twice or you will get a compilation error since MSbuild also use the .csproj file declarations to compile your project.